# Live notifications in a ToDo list app?

Tags: javascript, html, web, push-notification, service-worker

So I am trying to build a somewhat enhanced version of the to-do list app. What I want to achieve is to get a list of the pending tasks from users and store them locally inside the browser localStorage or any other alternative options. Then the user can close the web app if they want. Whenever the task deadline is near, the users will get a notification informing them about the concerned task.

The main part is the functionality of receiving the notifications even when the app is closed(browser is still open though). If the app were open or in an idle state in the background, it could have been simply done using the notifications API but it seems to be more difficult when the app is closed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API
Please guide. Thanks for reading. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I tend to find Google's Developersite is very useful. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/

Comment: @Crowes Thanks for the link. I have already skimmed through the article. I don't want any server intervention for this job. Service workers seem to  involve setting up a server which will send the response to the client who will display it using the Notifications API. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Not neccasarily. Service workers don't require a server, they're intended for handling application features from cached data whilst no connection to a service itself is available. In other words, cache your events, and then allow those notifications to be fired by the worker.

Comment: @CrowesThanks. Yeah it seems that the server is not required for setting up the service workers. But how would you send those notifications? All the lessons on the web are for push notifications from the server to the web and none of them talk about the local notifications which I am planning to achieve. It could be very simple but I am not really getting it. Could you please elaborate more on it? Thanks!!